# dropdown auto close when selected first, but the second select works properly vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-multiselect

i have problem when first select dropdow will close,
even though i have set `close-on-select="false"` the dropdown still hides after the first select, but since the next select it works properly 
you can see it directly at the homepage link: [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-asynchronous-select)

or you can watch the video here [video](https://tikho900-gmail.tinytake.com/df/13d8975/thumbnail?type=attachments&version_no=0&file_version_no=0&thumbnail_size=preview)

here is my code:

```
              <Multiselect
                v-model="form.users_ids"
                id="students"
                label="name"
                class="chat-bulk-form-mul"
                :custom-label="nameWithRelation"
                :options="optionUsers"
                :multiple="true"
                :clear-on-select="false"
                :close-on-select="false"
                :preserve-search="true"
                :hide-selected="true"
                :max-height="200"
                :internal-search="false"
                @async-find="asyncFind"
                @infinite-scroll="infiniteScroll"
              />
```

Comment: Can't see any issue. Can you provide a working demo?

Comment: you can watch the video here [video](https://tikho900-gmail.tinytake.com/df/13d8975/thumbnail?type=attachments&version_no=0&file_version_no=0&thumbnail_size=preview)

Comment: You want to close the drop-down if you chose any option right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure because your configuration seems correct. However, a new step is mentioned in the [documentation](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-getting-started), to add CSS via CDN. Maybe you forgot to add the proper CDNs.
One more reason could be, I can't see any event named `async-find` in the doc. There is a method named `asyncFind` which can be used when calling upon a search query.

Try matching your `asynFind` method and rest config with this example-

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <label>Simple select / dropdown</label>
    <multiselect
      v-model="value"
      :options="options"
      :multiple="true"
      :clear-on-select="false"
      :close-on-select="false"
      :preserve-search="true"
      :hide-selected="true"
      :max-height="200"
      :internal-search="false"
      label="name"
      track-by="name"
      :custom-label="customLabel"
      @search-change="asyncFind"
    >
    </multiselect>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Multiselect,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: [],
      options: [
        { name: "Vue.js", language: "JavaScript" },
        { name: "Adonis", language: "JavaScript" },
        { name: "Rails", language: "Ruby" },
        { name: "Sinatra", language: "Ruby" },
        { name: "Laravel", language: "PHP" },
        { name: "Phoenix", language: "Elixir" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    customLabel({ name, language }) {
      return `${name} – ${language}`;
    },
    asyncFind(query) {
      console.log(query);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
```

Here is the [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-shaw-3phgsw?file=/src/App.vue:0-1236).

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: i tried it directly on its homepage, here is the detailed video: [video](https://tikho900-gmail.tinytake.com/df/13da3fb/thumbnail?type=attachments&version_no=0&file_version_no=0&thumbnail_size=preview)